# Best methods to avoid MySQL 1406 errors on VARCHAR

Tags: mysql

My server is using a MySQL DB, connecting to it via the C++ connector. I'm nearing production and I've been spending some time trying to break things as part of hardening the server.

One action item I had was to see what would happen if I execute a statement with a string that is longer than `VARCHAR`. For example, if I have a column defined as `VARCHAR(4)` and then set it to the string "hello".

This of course throws an exception with the error code 1406 (Data too long for column).

What I was wondering was if there was a good or standard way to defend against this? Obviously one thing is to check against the string length and truncate manually. I can do this, however there are many tables and several columns with `VARCHAR`. So my worry is updating server code if one of the columns using `VARCHAR` has its length increased (i.e. code maintainability)

Note that the server does do some validation up front. I'm just trying to defend against a subtle bug or corner case that lets something slip through.

A couple of other options on the table are to disable strict so it will give a warning and truncate or to convert `VARCHAR` to `TEXT`.

I was wondering a few things.

- Is there a recommended method to handle this situation?
- What are the disadvantages of disabling strict?
- Is it worth (and is it possible) to query the DB at runtime the `VARCHAR` lengths? Note that I'm using the C++ connector. I suppose I could also write a tool that is run before compiling which would extract out `VARCHAR` lengths from the SQL code used to generate tables. But that then makes me wonder is I'm over engineering this.

I'm just sorting through the possible approaches now and thought I'd seek advice from those with more experience with MySQL.

Comment: Your C++ program logic should handle all user inputs and check the length **before** it goes to the DB.

Comment: @juergend understood. I recognize that. I was just looking for tradeoffs and ways to better manage the code since there are several tables and several columns with `VARCHAR`. In the end just adding the code may be the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an experience database engineer I would recommend a combination of the follow two strategies:
1) If you that know that a there is a chance, however small, that data for your varchar(4) could go higher than 4 then make the varchar field larger than 4. For example, if you expect that the field can go as high as 8 then set the field to varchar(10). The beauty of using a varchar field instead of a char is that a varchar will only use whatever storage it needs.
2) If there is a real issue with data constantly being larger than the varchar field length then you should right your own exception handler to trap for the 1406 error. For the exception to work properly you will need to come up with some type of strategy on exactly how you want to handle the exception. For example, you could send an error to the user and ask them to fix the problem, you could accept the data but truncated it so it fits into the field, or you could send the error to a log file to get fixed at a later time.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I will take a look at if the exception also provides the column number so I can ascertain which one was the issue. Part of what I'm trying to do is protect against someone that is trying to send bad data to test the server for weaknesses. The good news is it does handle the 1406 exception "properly" in that it won't crash the server and returns an error.